# Include column for has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I got three models, `User`, `Team` and `Membership`. In the Membership model a got a field, role, that stores the user role for the current team.

When a team got a lot of users and I list them and also show the user role for the team my query count explode of course.

Is there a way to load all the Team users and include the role column from the Membership model?

```
User
has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :teams,       through: :memberships 

Team
has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users,       through:   :memberships

Membership
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :team
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I belive this will work

```
team = Team.first #for example
users = team.users.select("*, memberships.role AS role")
```

so each user will get role

```
users.first.role
```